# Is Agora.io Cloud Recording sample Python code up to date?

Tags: api, rest, agora.io

To call the Agora.io Cloud Recording endpoints there are some resources in Agora.io documentation. One of them is through a Postman collection/environment like [in this blog post](https://medium.com/agora-io/agora-cloud-recording-quickstart-guide-with-postman-demo-c4a6b824e708), and there is also a [sample Python code](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_rest?platform=RESTful#a-namedemo-restasample-code) where you fill some variables, and the script does all the requests by itself.

I tested that Python code while having a call with myself in [this demo web app](https://digitallysavvy.github.io/group-video-chat/) that already implements Agora.io SDK. This one asks you for APPID, TOKEN, CHANNEL, and UID.

However, the result is that both the acquire and the start go fine (they have response code 200, returning the `resourceId` and then the `sid`), but the query, adjustLayout, and stop calls return a 404. There is a [specific documentation FAQ about this 404](https://docs.agora.io/en/All/faq/return-404), but I debugged all steps there and couldn't fix the issue.

The way I filled the variables in Python is the following:

- APPID: this one is easy to get.
- Auth: I used a Python snippet for this one: `"Basic " + base64.b64encode( (CUSTOMERID + ":" + - CUSTOMERCERTIFICATE).encode('ascii') ).decode('ascii')` and I trust this one since changing anything there makes it return an auth error.
- Cname: I used "hello" as channel name, and also used it on the web demo app.
- ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, VENDOR, REGION: I used an Amazon S3 bucket for this, and I trust these are set up correctly because I already used the exact same values to upload files from another script, and it worked fine.
- BUCKET: This one I'm not sure it's filled properly, but I tried with normal name "my-experiments", the ARN (Amazon Resource Name), and even the URL of the bucket.

Also the UID Python code uses is 123, I tried both matching and not matching this parameter in the call in the demo app, but none worked, and I already checked for more obvious gotchas like turning on Cloud Recording from the project dashboard.

This all makes me believe that this Python sample code could be slightly out of date (maybe the `recordingConfig`), although it's worth mentioning that the Postman collections aren't working for me neither after I fill the values in a similar way, so it could also be the case that I'm doing something wrong, but I'm clueless as I have tried most of the options.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: This is what the body of the calls look like:

Acquire:

```
{
  "cname": "{{AccessChannel}}",
  "uid": "{{RecordingUID}}",
  "clientRequest":{
  }
}
```

Start:

```
{
    "cname":"{{AccessChannel}}",
    "uid":"{{RecordingUID}}",
    "clientRequest":{
        "token":"{{token}}",
        "recordingConfig":{
            "maxIdleTime":120,
            "streamTypes":2,
            "audioProfile":1,
            "channelType":1,
            "videoStreamType":0,
            "transcodingConfig":{
                "width":360,
                "height":640,
                "fps":30,
                "bitrate":600,
                "mixedVideoLayout":1,
                "maxResolutionUid":"1"
            }
        },
        "storageConfig":{
            "vendor":{{Vendor}},
            "region":{{Region}},
            "bucket":"{{Bucket}}",
            "accessKey":"{{AccessKey}}",
            "secretKey":"{{SecretKey}}"
        }   
    }
}
```

[These are the values that fill those variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCwEO.png), the black rectangles are to protect the secret values there.

Comment: can you show your body? We use the Postman collection internally and have not experienced any issues. The issue you describe can be caused by many different things and I don't think the python code snippet is the reason. The issue you are describing is caused by the recording service failing to start, not anything specific to the language used to make the request.

Comment: Hi @Hermes, I updated the question with the bodies you are interested in (and the values). I also added the values that I'm using (I blocked them for safety). Thanks.

Comment: when you set `"region":{{Region}},` in postman, do you hardcode the region or use it as an env var? the reason I ask is because I noticed it works when the region is hardcoded otherwise postman sends the value as a string and it causes the recording to fail.

Comment: Hmmm, no, I was using the environment variable from Postman directly, no hardcoding. Still I just tested it out with hardcoded values and the call to Query/Stop returns 404 (call didn't start correctly). Just in case: SID: 7ccce13bc24b2e1dc5a4388642709c69. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: try hardcoding the region.

Comment: did hardcoding the region help resolve your issue?

Comment: @Hermes thanks a lot for following up. Sadly not, hardcoding didn't help resolve the issue and I'm still stuck. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What value are you passing for the bucket name? If you are using S3, the ARN is listed as `arn:aws:s3:::bucketname` but in cloud recording you only need to use the `bucket name` and can omit `arn:aws:s3:::` .. let me know if that helps